# Fast note progression - Terminology

Tags: terminology

I have no idea how to call these.
basically, it is when you have fast long strings of note progressions, spanning multiple octaves. These would be my examples, as I don't know how to describe it:
The part from 1:32 -

from 0:32

Since I have no idea what the musical term for this type of musical formula is, I can't really look for a way to improve my playing.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Could be glissando.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your description, I too thought like Tim that you were referring to glissando but listening to the recording, I think these are simply arpeggios on the left hand while the right hand is simply repeating two notes.

The right hand shouldn't present much challenge here, so you just need to practice your arpeggios.

One way to practice them is to play by position: i.e. you play as many of the notes as you can at once and then you move your hand to play the next group of notes.  This will help you memorize where your fingers should go.  You will also need to strengthen your fingers as well, and work on the most difficult transition where the fingers move over your thumb by, for example, repeating that transition multiple times when you play the arpeggio.

There you have your crash course on playing arpeggios assuming this is indeed what you wanted to learn about :-)